# How to pass any function as a parameter and execute it in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, parameter-passing

I'm trying to write a function that can take any function as a parameter and execute it in Swift. I have tried this approach:

```
public func anyFunc<P, T> (_ function: (P...) -> T) {
    _ = function()    
}
```

and then trying it with:

```
anyFunc(print("hello"))
```

This produces `ERROR: 'print' produces '()', not the expected contextual result type '(_...) -> _'`

How can I achieve this (and is it feasible)?

Comment: Why are you using `<P, T>`? Should the passed function returns void?

Comment: `print("hello")` is _a call_ to the function `print`, which returns a result (the empty tuple, `()`). Hence, your call to `anyFunc` is equivalent to `anyFunc(())`, which is naturally a mismatch for the arguments of `anyFunc`.

Comment: In general, how do you expect to call `function()` without passing any arguments if it takes an arbitrary number of arguments?

Comment: @dfri hence my question :-)

Comment: @jtbandes that's my question. How to achieve this (0 or more arguments).

Comment: I don't understand what you want. If you pass a function which requires 2 arguments to to `anyFunc`, what arguments is it supposed to use when calling the function?

Comment: @jtbandes if you pass a func with 2 args, AnyFunc executes this func with the two args. If you pass one with 0 args, it executes it with 0 args. If you pass one with 8 args, it executes it with the 8 args. _How do you pass any function as a parameter and then execute it_? I'm trying to implement the `debounce` method from here in Swift: https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about just using `@autoclosure`, like so:

```
func anyFunc<T>(_ closure: @autoclosure () -> T) {
  let result: T = closure()
  // TODO: Do something with result?
}

anyFunc(print("hello"))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I didn't know about `@autoclosure`. I also added a return type of `T` and `return result` at the end. Thanks